# Problem in setting variable "TWITTER_PAT" in Renviron

Tags: r, twitter, renviron

I keep getting the information "Problem in setting variable "TWITTER_PAT" in Renviron when I start R or R studio, I tried rm(TWITTER_PAT) or to uninstall the package rTweet that I used in the past, but nothing works. I also get the same message in the console when I run various lines of code, any ideas of how to remove it?

I tried rm(TWITTER_PAT) and to find and uninstall package rtweet.

Comment: Hello, please check your .Renviron-File in your HOME-Directory or by using usethis::edit_r_environ() and edit it manually.

Comment: If it's something that affects every session, check your `~/.Rprofile` file content (`Sys.getenv("R_USER")` to get the location, defaults to `%USERPROFILE%/Documents` in Windows)

Comment: Thank you both, I found the Renviron file and delete it, which fixed the issue for me.